# How do I find the time complexity of my program?

Tags: java, time, time-complexity

what is the time complexity of this program? I understand that time complexity has
something to do with the processor. here is the program

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Heelo, world!");
```

}

please give me time complexity of this program in java vs c++ vs c#

Sorry if noob question.

Answer (score 1):

> What is the time complexity of this program?

The complexity is `O(1)` ... because there is no scaling variable.

> I understand that time complexity has something to do with the processor.

Actually, it has almost nothing to do with "the processor".

However, explaining what Big O complexity (and similar) are really about is too large a task for StackOverflow answer.  Instead, I suggest you read the following Wikipedia pages:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity_theory

Or find a good textbook on algorithms.

> please give me time complexity of this program in java vs c++ vs c#

That is nonsensical.  The code is Java!

But an equivalent program in C++ or C# will also be `O(1)` ... for the same reason.